# Pagina Expirada Laravel, por que?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, http, http-request

Estou criando uma api rest aqui, por algum motivo eu recebo essa mensagem

```
"The page has expired due to inactivity. 

Please refresh and try again."
```

Segue Controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JWTAuth;
use App\User;
use JWTAuthException;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    private $user;
    public function __construct(User $user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function register(Request $request){

        $user = $this->user->create([
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'password' => bcrypt($request->get('password'))
        ]);
        return response()->json(['status'=>true,'message'=>'User created successfully','data'=>$user]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request){
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $token = null;
        try {
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['invalid_email_or_password'], 422);
            }
        } catch (JWTAuthException $e) {
            return response()->json(['failed_to_create_token'], 500);
        }
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
    public function getAuthUser(Request $request){
        $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->token);
        return response()->json(['result' => $user]);
    }
}
```

As rotas estão assim

```
Route::prefix('api/v1/')->group(function () {

    Route::post('register', 'UserController@register');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
        Route::get('user', 'UserController@getAuthUser');
    });

});
```

E o erro que recebo está assim

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

DETALHE: Está sendo criado um arquivo em Storage/framework/session a cada conexão mesmo que faço, exemplo, se conecto via PostMan ele cria um, se conecto via Chrome outro e assim vai!

Como solucionar?

Comment: O conceito ai é outra deve ser criado um token e não uma session

Comment: O Arquivo que ele cria dentro de session é isso :   a:2:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"zHZgdWW1brddvkcTgFlQvlkCatzJrwqzCYe8xK3k";s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}

Comment: Dá uma lida geral nisso: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#introduction

Comment: Outra também: https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps

Comment: Detalhe, só pra vc saber, eu tenho uma outra rota... Ao abrir essa rota, ela funciona perfeitamente. Talvez o problema seja na requisição, não?

Comment: Pode ser!!! também!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic resolvi aqui louco, precisava comentar a linha do CRSFToken se não ele esperaria o Token nos moldes do crsf_token e não funcionaria nunca... Mas vlw rapaz.